# How to use the range variable for the workbook which generated at the runtime

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to access a excel workbook which is generated at the run time

I am using this code
'

```
Dim w2 As Workbook

Dim r as range

Set w2 = Workbooks.Add

Set w2 = ActiveWorkbook

Set r = w2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(5, 4), Cells(5, 4))

r.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues'
```

Line no. 5 shows this error "application defined or object defined error"

can someone help me to fix this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** There is no need for this line:

```
Set w2 = ActiveWorkbook
```

because next line already returns new workbook object:

```
Set w2 = Workbooks.Add
```

**2)** You should fully qualify `Cells` object, i.e. you should specify to which workbook/sheet cells belongs:

```
Set r = w2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(w2.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, 4), w2.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, 4))
```

or shorter:

```
With w2.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set r = .Range(.Cells(5, 4), .Cells(5, 4))
End With
```

But since your `Range` object conatins only single cell, you can simply use:

```
Set r = w2.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, 4)
```